Keep bone in IK chain always pointing down
First time trying to rig something. I've got this sample project to recreate the core issue and needed helping figuring out how to get a specific bone in an IK chain to always be pointed down.

I have constraints on the "Point Sideways" bone for IK to the "IK Bone" and I have the IK LOCK set for X and Y axis.


For Rootbone, I have IK Lock on Y and Z axis with a Limit X set so it can only rotate up and down a certain amount.

What contraints do I need to put on "Point Down" bone to make sure that it's rotation will always compensate to allow for the bone it be pointing downwards at all times. The idea is that if you lift up on the IK bone, the "Point Sideways" bone will always stay perpendicular to the "Point Down" bone and the "Point Down" bone's angle will change to allow it always point down and then move the "Root Bone" up and down on it's locked axis.
I've tried using a reference bone, putting on location/rotation constraints but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Please insert images directly into your question rather than posting a link to them. That way they will be available to future users reading your question. How to upload an image to a post.


the "Point Sideways" bone will always stay perpendicular to the "Point Down"

Because this relationship won't change, we can treat the Point Sideways and Point Down elements as a single element.  Because these bones will never actually change their pose space orientation, we don't need to include them in the IK whatsoever.  We just need to find out where the first bone should point.  That's not so hard.

Notice the hierarchy in the outliner.
Because it's the only bone with undefined rotation, Root Bone is now our only bone in the IK chain; it targets a marker bone parented to what used to be our IK target.  In order to keep the position of marker correct, IK Bone has a locked track constraint (lock Y) targeting a new parent of Root Bone.  To maintain its orientation, Points Down is parented to IK Bone or mechanism, and then copies location from the tail of Root Bone.  For a solvable position of the control, copying location isn't necessary, but maybe you won't always have solvable positions.
Note that there are very few valid (solvable) positions for IK Bone, our control.  The only solutions for this lie on the surface of a sphere (which would be centered at the XY location of Root Bone but at the altitude of Points Sideways.)  You haven't specified how you'd like it to behave when there is no solution to the IK, so I haven't worried about that, assuming you will always give it a valid position.
When we move IK Bone, marker moves with it, so Root Bone points at it, and Point Down and Point Sideways maintain the components of their rotation with which you are concerned:

When IK Bone is rotated about the center of the structure, it rotates to face origin, and Points Down and Points Sideways keep pointing with the correct orientation:


Thanks! This is exactly what I needed! I didn't even think to just ignore those bones from the IK rig but it makes sense. You bring up a really good point with having a valid position at all times (something I didn't think about). I'll be sure to think through that point when I implement this concept fully. Really appreciate the help!
